# utf8 second byte lower bound in golang

Tags: go, unicode, utf-8

I was recently going through the go source code of utf8 decoding.
Apparently when decoding utf8 bytes, when the first byte has the value 224
(0xE0) it maps to an accept range of [0xA0;  0xBF].
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go#L81
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go#L94

If I understand the utf8 spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) correctly every continuation byte has the minimum value of 0x80 or 1000 0000. Why is the minimum value for opening byte with 0xE0 higher, i.e. 0xA0 instead of 0x80?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is to prevent so-called overlong sequences. Quoting the RFC:

> Implementations of the decoding algorithm above MUST protect against
>      decoding invalid sequences.  For instance, **a naive implementation may
>      decode the overlong UTF-8 sequence C0 80 into the character U+0000**,
>      or the surrogate pair ED A1 8C ED BE B4 into U+233B4.  Decoding
>      invalid sequences may have security consequences or cause other
>      problems.
>
> [...]
>
> A particularly subtle form of this attack can be carried out against
>      a parser which performs security-critical validity checks against the
>      UTF-8 encoded form of its input, but interprets certain illegal octet
>      sequences as characters.  For example, a parser might prohibit the
>      NUL character when encoded as the single-octet sequence 00, but
>      erroneously allow the illegal two-octet sequence C0 80 and interpret
>      it as a NUL character.  Another example might be a parser which
>      prohibits the octet sequence 2F 2E 2E 2F ("/../"), yet permits the
>      illegal octet sequence 2F C0 AE 2E 2F.  This last exploit has
>      actually been used in a widespread virus attacking Web servers in
>      2001; thus, the security threat is very real.

Also note the syntax rules in section 4 which explicitly only allow characters A0-BF after E0:

> ```
> UTF8-2      = %xC2-DF UTF8-tail  
> UTF8-3      = %xE0 %xA0-BF UTF8-tail / %xE1-EC 2( UTF8-tail ) /
>               %xED %x80-9F UTF8-tail / %xEE-EF 2( UTF8-tail )  
> UTF8-4      = %xF0 %x90-BF 2( UTF8-tail ) / %xF1-F3 3( UTF8-tail ) /
>               %xF4 %x80-8F 2( UTF8-tail )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If the first byte of an UTF-8 sequence is `0xe0`, that means it's a 3-byte sequence representing / encoding a Unicode codepoint (because `0xe0 = 1110 0000b`).

[Wikipedia: UTF-8:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

```
Number    Bits for    First       Last        Byte 1   Byte 2    Byte 3 
of bytes  code point  code point  code point 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
3         16          U+0800      U+FFFF      1110xxxx 10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx
```

The first Unicode codepoint that is encoded using 3-byte UTF-8 sequence is U+0800, so the codepoint is `0x0800`, in binary: `0000 1000 0000 0000`

If you try to insert these bits into the ones marked with `x`:

```
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
11110000 10100000 10000000
```

As you can see, the second byte is `1010 0000` which is `0xa0`. So a valid UTF-8 sequence that starts with `0xe0`: its 2nd byte cannot be lower than `0xa0` (because even the lowest Unicode codepoint whose UTF-8 encoded sequence starts with `0xe0` has a 2nd byte of `0xa0`).